Salesforce Winter 25 Error "This feature isn't available in Standard apps for your organization' with "Enhanced Omni-Channel Routing" set to off
It seems that with Salesforce Winter '25 Version, even if the option "Enhanced Omni-Channel Routing" is set to off in "Salesforce Setup" > "Omni-Channel Settings", I still receive the following error on the Omni channel widget:
This feature isn't available in Standard apps for your organization. For access, contact your administrator to upgrade to Enhanced Omni-Channel Routing.


Are standard organizations obliged to buy the new feature in order to use Omnichannel as normal (as in previous versions of Salesforce)?
Is there a way to turn off the new "Enhanced Omni-Channel Routing" feature and still use the omnichannel widget? Or can I downgrade the Salesforce version?
Thank you for your help!
Radu

Make sure that the "Service Cloud User" checkbox is enabled for users who need access to Omni-Channel

A 'Standard App' in this situation refers to a non-console app, and you shouldn't need to upgrade to utilise this feature.
There is an article in the Sprint '24 Release Notes about this and you should be able to use this without additional purchases.
There are a couple of caveats noted:

You can only use Status-based capacity models (not Tab based)
Service Cloud Voice and Messaging aren't supported
You must edit the app you have exposed Omni-Channel in once you have enabled Enhanced Omni-Channel

I'd recommend checking that none of these are causing the issue. If it was working and nothing has changed from the previous set up, then you might need to raise a case with Salesforce if it is definitely related to the release.
Also just to answer one additional aspect of your question, you can't downgrade to a previous major release.
